# MVC client-side validation for multiple models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three models: `VehicleType`, `VehicleModel`, and `VehicleManufacturer`.

Both `VehicleType` and `VehicleManufacturer` point to `VehicleModel` in the model, like so:

```
public class VehicleModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ModelId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is Required")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is Required")]
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }


    public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
    public VehicleManufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }

}
```

From there, VehicleModel points to the InventoryModel:

```
 public class Inventory
{
    [Key]
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }


    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public VehicleModel VehicleModel { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is when I try to get client-side validation working on all three dropdownlists (`VehicleType`, `VehicleManufacturer`, `VehicleModel`), it only works with `VehicleModel`.

What needs to be done to validate these two dropdownlists using these models?

Here is my controller (fyi):

```
 // GET: /Inventory/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.Types, "TypeId", "TypeName"); //(Object List, Value Field (usually Id), Column)
        ViewBag.ModelId = new SelectList(db.Models, "ModelId", "ModelName"); //(Object List, Value Field (usually Id), Column)
        ViewBag.ManufacturerId = new SelectList(db.Manufacturers, "ManufacturerId", "ManufacturerName"); //(Object List, Value Field (usually Id), Column)

        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Inventory/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Inventory inventory, VehicleManufacturer VehicleManufacturer, VehicleType VehicleType)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Inventorys.Add(inventory);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.Types, "TypeId", "TypeName");
        ViewBag.ModelId = new SelectList(db.Models, "ModelId", "ModelName");
        ViewBag.ManufacturerId = new SelectList(db.Manufacturers, "ManufacturerId",     "ManufacturerName");

        return View(inventory);
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VehicleModel.TypeId, "Some name for column")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("TypeId", String.Empty)

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleModel.TypeId)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelId, "Some name for column")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ModelId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelId)
    </div>



    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VehicleModel.ManufacturerId, "Some name for column")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleModel.ManufacturerId)
    </div>
```

Please someone help. I've been on this for many, many hours!

Comment: I don't see any validation attributes, did you forget to add it here or forgot them all together

Comment: You do not actually have any Validation Attribute. Also, beware validating a value type with a `RequiredAttribute` as they will always have a default (and therefore will always have a value).

Comment: Sorry guys, there was validation, I just didn't add to question

Comment: I suggest that instead of (or in addition to) the `RequiredAttribute` you use the `Range` attribute. This will allow you to validate the dropdownlist. Since these are `int` values, it will always have a value of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two problems That I see above

**1)** That you're not mapping the DropDownList and the ValidationMessageFor to the same model attribute.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleModel.ManufacturerId)
```

The above is binding it to `VehicleModel_ManufacturerId` where as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", String.Empty)
```

the above is mapping the DropDown to just `ManufacturerId`

You need to change one or the other to match each other.

**2)** In the above code, I don't see any Validation Attributes. did you forgot them when you copied the code over here?

Hope this helps, Let me know if you needed more details.

Comment: When I match them this way:     @Html.DropDownList("VehicleModel.ManufacturerId", String.Empty)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleModel.ManufacturerId)

Error:There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'VehicleModel.ManufacturerId

When I try the other way:
            @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManufacturerId)

 CS1061: 'Dealership.Models.Inventory' does not contain a definition for 'ManufacturerId' and no extension method 'ManufacturerId'

Comment: Why not just use `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VehicleModel.ManufacturerId, ViewBag.ManufacturerId)`

Comment: Also, you should really try to use ViewModels instead of ViewBags

Comment: I just tried, and CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Dealership.Models.Inventory>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. I tried casting it, so I changed it to:@Html.DropDownListFor("ManufacturerId", (SelectList) ViewBag.ManufacturerId) but I get error:CS0411: The type arguments for method etc...
Maybe I'll have to go back and study using ViewModels, because I honestly have ViewBag

Comment: I appreciate your help though @hjavaher

Comment: No prblem. I will try to workout an example for you to try when I get off from work tonight. and No problem at all!